# How can I be notified when a new bounty has been offered on a tag

Tags: support, tags, bounty, notifications

Is there anyway I can be notified when someone places a bounty on any question in a certain tag space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the RSS feed on the *featured* tab for that tag.

Go to a tag page, click on the *featured* tab and scroll down to the bottom to look for the *featured <tagname> questions list* link:

> [image: Python tag featured feed link with RSS icon]

Add the link to your favourite RSS reader.

Comment: I was hoping for an actual badge in the inbox, but this works too.